# Vue .native on events sometimes needed and sometimes not (within the same component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vue-native

I just experienced something I don't understand with a running vue app.
I have a button, which is included in muliple parent components.
I just added some eventlisteners for `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

In one case I have to call the function with `.native` and when the button component is used in another parent, I have to leave it away to be called.

For the sake of completeness I leave everything of my template in here:

```
<template>
  <component
    :is="computedType"
    ref="button"
    :class="[$options.name, { 'is-reversed': reversed, 'is-naked': naked, 'is-disabled': disabled, 'has-inverted-textcolor': invertedTextColor }]"
    :style="backgroundColor ? `background-color: ${backgroundColor}` : false"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :aria-disabled="disabled"
    :to="!external ? to : false"
    :aria-controls="ariaControls"
    :aria-expanded="ariaExpanded"
    :target="!target && external && mailto ? '_blank' : target"
    :type="computedType === 'button' ? buttonType : false"
    :rel="external ? 'noopener' : false"
    @click="click"
    @mouseover.native="triggerHover"
    @mouseout.native="releaseHover"
    @mouseover="triggerHover"
    @mouseout="releaseHover"
  >
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>
```

You can see that I now added the `@mouseover` and `@mouseover.native` to cover both cases.

I would really be interested in what causes the difference here.
To be honest, I don't fully understand the [part in the vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components).

I also realized that I register a difference in how I can access the style properties of my DOM element.
I gave it a reference: `ref="button"` and I would normally access it via:

`this.$refs.button.style.backgroundColor`
But in the case where I need the `.native` to call the method, I also need `$el` to access the stlye propperty: `this.$refs.button.$el.style.backgroundColor`.

I now not only don't understand what's exactly going on but I also have a problem that my button component will fail in one of the two cases, because I can't access the style property in the same way.

The only difference in how I use the component is, that in one case the button appears in a `v-for`-loop. Everything else is exactly the same.
Is this causing the different behaviour?

Thank you for some background information about that.
Cheers

---

### Edit

Here are my parent component templates:

This is where I must use `@mouseout` without native:

```
<template>
  <div class="TwoColumnModule">
    <div class="TwoColumnModule__text">
      <BRichtext v-if="component.text" class="TwoColumnModule__richtext TwoColumnModule__BRichtext" :content="component.text" />
      <BBtn
        v-if="component.button_checkbox"
        class="TwoColumnModule__BBtn"
        :inverted-text-color="component.button_text_color"
        :background-color="component.button_color"
        :target="component.button_link.target"
        :to="checkLinkIfInternal(component.button_link.url) ? prepareNuxtLink(component.button_link.url) : component.button_link.url"
        :external="typeButton"
        :href="checkLinkIfInternal(component.button_link.url) ? false : component.button_link.url"
        :hover-color="component.button_color_hover"
      >
        {{ component.button_link.title }}
      </BBtn>
    </div>

    
    <!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html -->
    <div
      v-else
      class="TwoColumnModule__video"
      v-html="component.vimeo_video"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is where I need `.native` and must access the reference via
`this.$refs.button.$el`:

```
<template>
  <div class="Storyboard">

    <BHeading v-if="component.main_title" :level="3" class="Storyboard__heading Storyboard__BHeading">{{ component.main_title }}</BHeading>

    <div v-for="(item, index) in component.four_column_layout" :key="index" class="Storyboard__item--four-columns">
      
      <BRichtext v-if="item.text" class="Storyboard__richtext Storyboard__BRichtext" :content="item.text" />
      <BBtn
        v-if="item.button.button_checkbox"
        class="TwoColumnModule__BBtn"
        :inverted-text-color="item.button.button_text_color"
        :background-color="item.button.button_color"
        :target="item.button.button_link.target"
        :to="checkLinkIfInternal(item.button.button_link.url) ? prepareNuxtLink(item.button.button_link.url) : item.button.button_link.url"
        :external="checkIfTypeButton()"
        :href="checkLinkIfInternal(item.button.button_link.url) ? false : item.button.button_link.url"
        :hover-color="item.button.button_color_hover"
      >
        {{ item.button.button_link.title }}
      </BBtn>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Entirely depends on your component template. Include that for any meaningful answer. In short, `.native` listens to the component's root element events. If root element has such events, then it is handled, if component has custom event with that same name, `.native` handler will not handle that.

Comment: You mean the parent's template? I will add them in a minute. Thank you for the comment. I still don't fully understand though. About which component's root element are you talking about. Are you talkin about my button component or the component in which I use it? I also don't use any custom events, especially not with the name `mouseover`. But I guess I still missing out on something...

Comment: You are subscribing to an event. Question is Whose event is that? Who do you expect the event to be raised? Some component right? That component's is what I was talking about.

Comment: Yeah exactly. And that would be my dynamic component button. But I use the very same component in both cases and the event, I am listening to, is the button's event. So that is what makes me wonder, why I see a difference in behaviour there...